# 'const' scope issue when using Karma/Mocha in Chrome with Babel and Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, mocha.js, karma-runner, babeljs

I am facing an issue following a Chrome update that appears to have broken all of my unit tests where 'const' has been used to require my dependencies. These tests work fine in other browsers such as Firefox, and had been working in Chrome up to the point of the update.

Current Chrome Version: Version 56.0.2924.87

At the moment I am satisfied that I have ruled out npm package updates as a cause.

**My set up is as follows -**

A typical test file might look like this -

```
const React = require('react'):
const TestUtils = require('react-addons-test-utils');
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const ExampleComponent = require('ExampleComponent.jsx');

describe('Example Component', () => {
    it('Should render component', () => {
        const objComponent = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(React.createElement(ExampleComponent, {});
        const objComponentHtmlElement = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(objComponent);
        expect(objComponentHtmlElement).to.not.be.undefined;
    });
});
```

My tests have been written this way for the past year and have worked seemlessly during this time. However, following a Chrome update, my dependencies are now seemingly undefined. Changing 'const' to 'var' solves this issue, as does(very strangely), moving describe to the top of the file -

```
describe('Example Component', () => {
    const React = require('react'):
    const TestUtils = require('react-addons-test-utils');
    const expect = require('chai').expect;
    const ExampleComponent = require('ExampleComponent.jsx');

    it('Should render component', () => {
        const objComponent = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(React.createElement(ExampleComponent, {});
        const objComponentHtmlElement = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(objComponent);
        expect(objComponentHtmlElement).to.not.be.undefined;
    });
});
```

**Karma.conf.js**

```
module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: __dirname,


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'sinon'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        'tests/test_unit/Globals.js',
        __dirname + '/node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.js',
        __dirname + '/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        __dirname + '/node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js',
        __dirname + '/client/lib/kendo.all.min.js',
        __dirname + '/client/lib/vender/speechkitt.min.js',
        __dirname + '/client/lib/canvasjs.min.js',
        __dirname + '/client/lib/DateRangePickerSrc/daterangepicker.js',
        'tests/test_unit/client/**/*Spec.js',
        'tests/test_unit/lib/**/*Spec.js',
        'tests/test_integration/client/**/*Spec.js',
        { pattern: __dirname + '/client/assets/images/**/*.*', watched: false, included: false, served: true }
    ],
    proxies: {
        '/static/images': '/base/client/assets/images'
    },
    preprocessors: {
        'tests/test_unit/client/**/*Spec.js': ['webpack'],
        'tests/test_unit/lib/**/*Spec.js': ['webpack'],
        'tests/test_integration/client/**/*Spec.js': ['webpack']
    },
    webpack: webpackConfig,
    webpackMiddleware: {
        noInfo: true
    },
    client: {
        mocha: {
            timeout: 2000
        },

        captureConsole: false
    },
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 100000,
    singleRun: true,
    concurrency: Infinity,
    browsers: ['Chrome']
});
```

};

**webpack.conf.js**

```
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var ProgressBarPlugin = require('progress-bar-webpack-plugin');

var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, '.static');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'client');

var config = {
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', APP_DIR + '/bundleIndex.js'],
    context: __dirname,
    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        filename: 'app.js'
    },
    eslint: {
        failOnWarning: true,
        failOnError: true
    },
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',

    plugins: [
        new ProgressBarPlugin(),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {
                from: 'client/assets'
            },
            {
                from: 'client/index.html'
            },
            {
                from: 'client/lib'
            },
            {
                from: './node_modules/react-grid-layout/css/styles.css',
                to: 'react-grid-layout-styles.css'
            },
            {
                from: './node_modules/react-resizable/css/styles.css',
                to: 'react-resizable-styles.css'
            },
            {
                from: './node_modules/react-bootstrap-multiselect/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css',
                to: 'bootstrap-multiselect.css'
            }
        ], {
            ignore: [
                'settings.js',
                'common.js'
            ]
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css')
    ],

    module: {
        noParse: [/ajv.bundle.js/],
        preLoaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loaders: ['eslint'],
                include: [
                    path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
                    path.join(__dirname, 'server'),
                    path.join(__dirname, 'lib')
                ],
                exclude: [
                    path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'asserts'),
                    path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'styles'),
                    path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'lib'),
                    path.join(__dirname, 'server', 'Data')
                ]
            }
        ],
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?/,
                include: [
                    path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
                    path.join(__dirname, 'lib')
                ],
                loader: 'babel'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css?/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader')
            },
            {
                include: /\.json$/,
                loaders: ['json-loader']
            }
        ]
    }
};
module.exports = config;
```

Has anyone else experienced this kind of issue? I'm struggling to see where to turn next - I can modify all the tests but I'm not really happy doing so not knowing the cause of the problem.

Comment: This must be narrowed to a [mcve]. What you have is not "Minimal" which harms the ability of readers to replicate your problem. You should be able to narrow this down to a set of files that someone could copy-paste on their side to replicate the behavior you report. It is reasonable that people reading the question would have to install libraries that are obviously part of the issue (e.g. Karma, Webpack) but it is unreasonable to expect a reader to have to install things that most likely have no bearing on the issue and leave it up to them to figure out what really impacts the issue.